# Shell script loop for printing lines doesn't match

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I've to display all lines doesn't match on files "inventory.txt" and "monitored_servers.txt". I was able to print all lines that match, as you can see below:

```
for i in `cat inventory.txt`; do grep $i monitored_servers.txt >> result.txt; done
```

How to display all lines doesn't match?

Comment: Aside: [Don't Read Lines With `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: Also, the above (running `grep` once per word in the inventory) is *really* slow. Even for the positive case, you'd get much better performance with just one grep invocation processing the whole inventory.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -v -f inventory.txt monitored_servers.txt >non-matching.txt
```

Comment: `-x` might be important too

Comment: @janos, ...maybe, but since the OP is satisfied with the result in their original usage, I'm not convinced.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -v --file inventory.txt monitored_servers.txt
```

`-v` - lines that don't match

`--file` - using your file as template

Comment: Think I beat you there by 25 seconds. :)

Comment: Damn , you're quick ;)

Comment: \o/  :D   

Tks a lot!